# Can I take a photo of my desktop through Android Emulator camera?

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-emulator, android-camera

I'd like to capture my desktop through the back camera of my emulator. I'm aware that you can set it to use your computers webcam or even a remote camera but I haven't found any information on using the camera to take a photo on what is behind the emulator window.

The reason I'd like to do this is that I have a presentation to give of my app which is done over a desktop sharing session. So I cannot easily demonstrate with a genuine device.

I'd therefore like to be able to move one emulator over the other so that I may take a photo of a QR code that the second QR code generated.

Is this possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) and [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm). Both of them are free, and can mirror your phone on the screen of your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I guess mirroring will have to do. Will accept your answer for now but will change it if someone is able to directly answer my question. Cheers